# Display Image on JSP from XML (SOAP Resposne)

Tags: java, xml, jsp, soap

I have got an **XML (SOAP Response)** which contains some data and an **image** something like the following

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <MapResultSet>
      Some Data values
   </MapResultSet>
   <Image>
      abcxyz
   </image>
```

According to client the image is in **Byte Array**.

I am thinking to pass this **response to JSP page** and extract the contents of XML and display them on JSP.

Data values can be displayed easily but i don't know **how to display the image**??

Am i doing it right?
or should i go for any other approach?

like Serialization and DeSerialization of XML and then putting the data on Response and then display on JSP?

I think there would be no use of Servlet because i can pass the Response easily to JSP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIU, you have at least 2 options:

1. Save image to a file and provide a link.
2. Use [data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) URI scheme.

Comment: Data URI Scheme worked. it displayed the image
Thanks :)
But i have an Google Map image which is big in size so are there any negative aspect of using this scheme?

Comment: @BaderJavaid: You'd better use e.g. google maps image API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis) then.

Comment: You are right i should use google maps image API..
But the thing is i am not directly calling google maps image API.
I am calling a third party Web Service which returns me a static image in byte array format.
I wanted to ask that is there any chance of Data loss? or heavy loading by using Data URI Scheme?

Comment: I tested it and it displayed the image

Comment: If you encode image data as base64 string you will get some overhead. You could simply cache images locally (e.g.: a) check that requested image is in local cache; b) if it is, just provide a link to it; c) if it is not, get an image data from web service and go to b).